# iOS UIRefreshControl in single view application, no table

Tags: ios, uirefreshcontrol

I would like to use the UIRefreshControl in my iPhone app to trigger a refresh of several UISwitch controls but it appears that the refresh control is meant to only work with a table view.  Is this true?  Any recommendations to get this functionality without a table?

Answer (score 3):

There is an open source control that mimics the appearance of iOS6's UIRefreshControl. It also works with iOS older versions and controls other than UITableView:

https://github.com/Vortec4800/ODRefreshControl

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but if you read my question, I asked specifically for an implementation that DOES NOT require a table view.

Comment: Yeah, the description of ODRefreshControl says it works for `UIScrollView`s and therefore for many more than only UITableViews.
Moreover, I am sure you could analyze the code and implement it for plain UIViews, too.
PS: I have read your question